# How do I mount an encrypted drive

Tags: encryption

I just got a new harddrive, and I would like to get the files off of my old drive that was encrypted using the full disk encryption option in the Ubuntu installer.  How do I access those files?

Comment: Enter passphrase and boot Ubuntu normally. In case, the drive have failed and Ubuntu cannot be booted, Restore everything from backups.

Answer (score 1):

If your old drive/partition is encrypted with cryptsetup/LUKS, then this command should decrypt it (or at least tell you if it's a LUKS device or not):

```
cryptsetup open /dev/<partition> name
```

and then mounting the decrypted partition with

```
mount /dev/mapper/name /newmountpoint
```

See `man cryptsetup` for more info.

It's also possible that the decrypted volume (here the `/dev/mapper/name` part) could have something other than a single formatted filesystem. It could have multiple partitions ("volumes") LVM style, or even look like a full disk with separate partitions, and a MBR or GPT, but I don't think Ubuntu normally does "full disk encryption" like that.

And like the comment said, *if* you can just boot from the drive there's a (good?) chance it'll work, and let you copy/backup the decrypted data.